# JSON to Core Data SQLITE Error

Tags: ios, json, sqlite, core-data

Can anyone help figure out what i've done wrong within this code? trying to populate core data structure through JSON file

```
// Create the managed object context
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = managedObjectContext();
    // Save the managed object context
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error while saving %@", ([error localizedDescription] != nil) ? [error localizedDescription] : @"Unknown Error");
        exit(1);
    }

    NSError* err = nil;
    NSString* dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Exercises" ofType:@"json"];
    NSArray* Exercises = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath]
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                          error:&err];
    //NSLog(@"Imported Exercises: %@", Exercises);
    NSManagedObject *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSString *theJSONString = @"{\"key\":\"value\"}";
    NSError *theError = NULL;
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithJSONString:theJSONString error:&theError];

    Exercise *exercise = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercise"
                                                       inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [Exercises enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        NSDictionary *attributes = [[object entity] attributesByName];
        for (NSString *attribute in attributes) {
            id value = [jsonDict objectForKey:attribute];
            if (value == nil) {
                continue;
            }
            [exercise setValue:value forKey:attribute];
        }
        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
```

Edited:
Code now compiles but i get null values in the core data model.
Thanks

Comment: In this code you're actually not saving anything. The save calls will do nothing. Where is the Entity subclass to feed the value of your JSON data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this isn't a SQLite error, it's a standard, basic Objective-C error. You'd have the same problem even if you weren't using a SQLite-based Core Data store.

Let's work backward from where it looks like the error is occurring, which is:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [[obj entity] attributesByName];
```

You're calling `entity` on `obj`. But where did `obj` come from? From here:

```
[Exercises enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
```

OK, so `obj` came from `Exercises`. What is in `Exercises`?

```
NSArray* Exercises = [NSJSONSerialization
    JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath]
    options:kNilOptions
    error:&err];
```

`Exercises` is an array of things that `NSJSONSerialization` gave you. The `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` method gives you Cocoa equivalents for the JSON content. **It does not give you managed objects**. In this case it looks like your JSON produced an array of `NSDictionary`.

So what happened is:

1. You used `NSJSONSerialization` and got an array of dictionaries
2. You iterated over that array
3. You attempted to call `entity` on the members of the array, only the array members are `NSDictionary` instances, and that class does not implement `entity`.

Your code never creates any Core Data objects, anywhere. That's why you're not getting any Core Data objects. Your code is crashing because you're trying to call Core Data methods on objects that don't implement those methods.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your reply, i was first using the "ugly/crude" way to populate core data with JSON. As posted on your post in cocoa is my gf. I then tried to implement NSDictionary way to the original code that i had. How would i create a core data object "Exercises" that can be used with NSDictionary category with touchJSON. Thank you

Comment: Create a managed object using one of the standard ways, e.g. `[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:]`. My posts on CIMGF were about how to get the data from JSON to the managed object, but you still need to create the managed object first.

Comment: Can this process be used for multiple entities? and one to many relationships?

Comment: With more than one instance you'd have to handle the object / JSON dictionary pairs one at a time, but you could do that as many times as you wanted. You'll have to find some other way to handle relationships-- it's not like JSON has a standard for that anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your help, ive managed to edit the code which allows it to compile, but upon examining the contents in the sqlite database created, the entries are all null...

Comment: Could be any number of things, try asking a new question with some details.